# Как корректно выполнить команду lsblk через python в Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Пытаюсь выполнить linux-команду lsblk и вывести их (stdout). Всё выводится, кроме столбца FSTYPE. Не понимаю почему данные из этого столбца не отображаются. В какую сторону подумать?

```
import sys
import subprocess

f = open('text.txt', 'r')



stdout_file = sys.stdout
stdout_file.write(f.read())

x = 'nvme0n1'

Y = subprocess.run(['lsblk', '-o', 'NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8').stdout
print(Y)
print(type(Y))
```

Вывод:

```
NAME      FSTYPE   SIZE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1          476,9G disk 
nvme0n1p1          512M part 
nvme0n1p2        476,4G part /run/host/share/icons
```

Comment: с флагом -J получается так:
`{"name":"nvme0n1p2", "fstype":null, "size":"476,4G", "type":"part", "mountpoint":"/run/host/share/icons"}`

Comment: Использовать соответствующий биндинг.  Хотя stackoverflow.com/a/60097858/2511795 говорят можно достать JSON.

Comment: Пробовал и json, все значения fstype определяет как null, это неверно, в консоле другие значения.

Comment: В моей версии `lsblk` вообще этого поля нет. `NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT`.

Comment: проблема в pycharm. другим idle все отображается верно

Comment: А как в консоли выглядит?
Вы не из под рута в консоли запускаете?
К вопросу куда копать - посмотреть как pycharm огораживает процессы. Может там виртуальное окружение какое?

Comment: По strace видно, что lsblk читает эти данные из /proc/self/mountinfo.
Попробуйте прочитать его напрямую.
Возможно, pycharm запускает ваш код в chroot, в который не смонтирован /proc.
Может быть это настраивается в pycharm.